# Update WallPaper with text using c#

Tags: c#

I am doing an application that runs in background. Since there are no forms, I need to show some info on the desktop wallpaper. how can i achieve this ? The application need to update the info on wallpaper.

Comment: Are you sure you dont' want to use system tray notifications, sidebar widget or even separate widget application, which monitors background process? I dont' think modifying wallpaper is a good idea anyway.

Comment: @Max, thats a good idea. Is it possible to make a widget application  using c#

Comment: If you mean a WinVista/Win7 sidebar widget - i don't think so, but you can make a form, which acts like widget (it might be tricky, for example, making it always stay behind all windows and never activate, you'll need some WinAPI, but it should be still possible in C#). You can even set part of wallpaper as a background when form is moved, so it looks transparent.

Comment: Remind me to steer clear of your application if it does end up modifying the wallpaper in anyway. I don't want my sports cars touched!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### U want no forms? I give U Transparent Forms!

---

Try implementing a single form with your custom message/text written on it.

This solves the problem of :

- NOT having to write directly to the wallpaper &
- NOT having to use use systray/widget-bar/notification

You might want to check this out **[XparentFormsCS on c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/XparentFormsCS10282007212944PM/XparentFormsCS.aspx)**

---

***NOTE:*** The pop-up balloon with ur text does seem a very cute-alternative though.

Answer (score 2):

In order to change the system wallpaper, you'll need to invoke the SystemParameterInfo API. 
This function is well documented, look for it in google.

If you need to write something on the wallpaper, you might try to output the text in the image before passing that on to SystemParameterInfo.

This means that every time you need to change the text, you'll need to start again from the original image and add the new text.

Comment: Is it possible to use a form as my wallpaper ? So that i can have a transparent Label and update text before making my form as wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a windows service which writes to the event log or something else. Windows offers diverse possibilites, writing text to the desktop directly should never be used in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, you can activate the web (HTML) desktop to a local HTML page, and update that page with your Winservice, but this is surely not a winget.